# Angular: adding row to table - No value accessor for form control

Tags: angular

I am building an angular app where I will be adding an item to a table.
The added row will be based on the input of an item name, and its quantity.

For example, if apples are being selected with 3 as Qty, I will expect a column with apples and 3 displayed in the table.

After pressing the add button, a row do get created, but the entry "apples" and 3 did not show up.

According to the console output, I get "No value accessor for form control with name: '[object Object]'" at line 66.

This is line 66:

`<td><label [(ngModel)]="item.name" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{item.name}}"></label></td>`

[image: Error]

[image: Console]

Here is my code:

app.component.html

```
<section>
  <form action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addItems()">Add Item</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select [(ngModel)]="newItem.name" name="newItemName">
            <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o">{{o.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newItemQuantity" pattern="[0-9]*" required [(ngModel)]="newItem.quantity" name="newItemQuantity">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <td><label [(ngModel)]="item.name" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{item.name}}"></label></td> // this is line 66
        <td><label [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{item.quantity}}"></label></td>
        <td><label [(ngModel)]="item.price" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{item.price}}"></label></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="delete" (click)="removeItem(i)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Taxes 7%</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {
  items: Array<any> = [];
  newItem: any = {};
  options = [
    {name: "Please Select...", price: 0},
    {name: "apples", price: 1.19},
    {name: "peaches", price: 1.39},
    {name: "pears", price: 1.69},
    {name: "plums", price: 1.59}
  ];

  addItems() {
    this.items.push(this.newItem);
    this.newItem = {};
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1); // remove 1 item at ith place
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code here

refer working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-row-in-table)

app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 items: Array<any> = [];
  newItem: any = {};
  options = [
    {name: "Please Select...", price: 0},
    {name: "apples", price: 1.19},
    {name: "peaches", price: 1.39},
    {name: "pears", price: 1.69},
    {name: "plums", price: 1.59}
  ];

  addItems() {
    this.items.push(this.newItem);
    console.log(this.items);
    this.newItem = {};
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1); // remove 1 item at ith place
  }

}
```

App.component.html

```
<section>
  <form action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addItems()">Add Item</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select [(ngModel)]="newItem.name" name="newItemName">
            <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o">{{o.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newItemQuantity" pattern="[0-9]*" required [(ngModel)]="newItem.quantity" name="newItemQuantity">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <td><span  class="form-control">{{item.name.name}}</span></td> 
        <td><span >{{item.quantity}}</span></td>
        <td><span class="form-control" >{{item.name.price}}</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="delete" (click)="removeItem(i)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Taxes 7%</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dump your object to see where are the values.
[Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

```
<td>
  {{ item | json}}
  <label 
    [(ngModel)]="item.name" 
    class="form-control" 
    type="text" 
    name="{{item.name}}">
  </label>
</td>
```